# Adding a right border to the last table header column

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

How can I add a border-right: 1px solid #808080, to the last column header of my table? I am unsure and stuck as to what to modify or fix.

Here is my CSS and a paste Bin: http://pastebin.com/CEPVfd1z

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
        height: 150px;
        width: 800px;
        border: 1px solid #808080;
        position: relative;

        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        scrollbar-base-color: #DFDFDF;
        scrollbar-arrow-color: #235A81;

}
#data {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0;
  width: 800px;
}
#data th {
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#cdcdcd");
}
#data td {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
}
#data tr:first-child th {
  border-top: 0;
}
#data tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#data tr td:first-child,
#data tr th:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Your table doesn't have complete syntax. I see no thead or tbody tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `#data th:last-child` as the selector and then add the `border-right` property into that. Seems like you already know how to use `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors, so I'm not going to explain.

http://jsfiddle.net/KgXuN/

```
#data th:last-child {
    border-right: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: @isherwood, good edit. I like to keep things clean (not too condensed).

Comment: Thanks Albert. I see it in Firefox but not IE7, is there a work around?

Comment: The workaround is to abandon IE7 and encourage your users to do the same. ;-)